# Can't seem to get setupProxy.js working with Duende ASP.NET Core BFF and TypeScript React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, duende

I can't seem to get the proxying to work for local development when trying to set up a Duende BFF with ASP.NET Core 6 and a TypeScript version of create react app.

Here's the repo I've been working in: https://github.com/dahlsailrunner/duende-bff-react-typescript

It's based on the sample from Duende which works fine: https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/IdentityServer/v6/BFF/ReactBffSample

I'm simply trying to get a new version of the same thing that uses the TypeScript version of React.

If I leave the `ClientApp/src/setupProxy.js` file named as-is, the React app seems to build, but it never loads in the browser (the output from the react scripts all seems fine and it says it *should* be in the browser, but I always get "connection refused".  This remains true even if I comment out every line in `setupProxy.js`.

If I rename the file in any way (make it a `.ts` file, or add `-bak` to it), everything loads fine on the site but the proxy to the backend/BFF doesn't work.

I've tried adding `src/setupProxy.js` to the `exclude` list in `tsconfig.json` as mentioned as a workaround [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5587?msclkid=8eeccc3cb66311ec8e3dff93313ca08d).

I'm guessing I'm missing something simple but just haven't been able to see it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Wow - it turns out that the only problem from the code was that the version of `http-proxy-middleware` npm package was too current.  Downgrading it to `"http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1"` did the trick - no other changes needed.

Comment: only just found this answer, been stuck on this for days.  Thanks !